# Is the batch axis included in available axes of a softmax layer?

Tags: keras

When specifying the axis in a softmax layer:

```
out = keras.layers.Softmax(axis=x)(in)
```

Is the batch/example dimension included? In other words, if under the hood I have (example, dim1, dim2, features) and I want to softmax over dim1, is that `axis=0` or `axis=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the batch dimension is included. For your situation, you would want `axis=1`.